# Unable to Delete data from data grid view

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I encountered a problem where when the user select the id from the data grid view and click the 'delete' button, A error prompts us like this: "Input string was not in the correct format".

Here are the codes to make you guys have better understanding of the codes.

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            int ID = Int32.Parse(lblID.Text);
            var DeleteSL = (from delLS in Setupctx.locationstations
                           where delLS.locationstationID == ID
                           select delLS).Single();
            Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteSL);
            Setupctx.SaveChanges();
            this.Delete_LS_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Location Station Has Been Deleted.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint to find which line is exactly giving the error?

Comment: Make sure `lblID.Text` has a numeric value inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception *"Input string was not in a correct format."* on

```
int ID = Int32.Parse(lblID.Text);
```

Your `lblID.Text` holds some thing which can't be converted to a number. May be something that contains characters along with numbers.

Try using [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to see if you can convert the text to number.

```
int ID;
if(!int.TryParse(lblID.Text, out ID))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number in lblID.Text");
}
```

Comment: but my linq query stated that "where delLS.locationstationID == ID" means that it only have integer that is inside it.

Comment: @user1553650, its not the LINQ query, you are getting the exception before that while parsing to Int

Comment: The error moved on to the LINQ query section that stated Sequence contains more then one element.

Comment: @user1553650, now thats a different error and that is because you are using `Single()`, If you are expecting Single result only from the result set then your ID is repeated in the database. If you expect the ID to be repeated then use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Single()`

Comment: in regard of my create for this table, Whenever the user create the table, the id won't increase and in fact the id of the created data is set as 0 for every data created for that table? Why is it happening?

Comment: That's explain why the delete command is not working because 0 is not part of the integer.

Comment: @user1553650, 0 is part of integer. The reason it is not working is because you are using Single. The problem with the ID is that you are not incrementing or haven't set the Identity field (Autoincrement) in the database.

Comment: Hmm. By changing to FirstOrDefault and using int.tryparse works, but my problem now is that whenever I create new data, the ID of it will always be 0. Why is it so?